# converting .txt with space as delimiter to .csv with comma as delimiter

Tags: python

I try to convert .txt file with space ad delimiter to .csv file with N-rows and 3 columns. When i try this, it just get 69 rows and 1 column.

```
data = pd.read_csv (r'C:"my path".txt', header = None)
data.columns = ['Temperature', 'Growth rate', 'Bacteria']
data.to_csv (r'C:"mypath".csv', index=None)
```

The i get:

```
0   39.122 0.81021 1
1    13.534 0.5742 1
2   56.137 0.20517 1
3    50.019 0.4754 1
4   24.297 0.86149 1
..               ...
64  14.769 0.17958 4
65  17.326 0.23037 4
66  41.557 0.38979 4
67  52.966 0.26035 4
68  58.711 0.15578 4

[69 rows x 1 columns]
```

And i just want to have 3 rows :///

Comment: try specifying a delimiter in your `read_csv` and also look at `delim_whitespace` while you are at it

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
data = pd.read_csv (r'C:"my path".txt',sep='\s+', header = None, index_col=False, usecols=['Temperature', 'Growth rate', 'Bacteria'])
data.to_csv (r'C:"mypath".csv', index=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = pd.read_csv (r'C:"my path".txt', header = None, sep=' ')
```

You need to specify the delimiter to be a space when reading in the file. By default the delimiter is a comma (','), so it takes everything to be in the same column.

Comment: thanks :)))) feel so very stupid right now